# Paho MQTT client disconnected and no more message incoming after reconnection

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, paho

I've a Rspi with MQTT Paho Client on it
I've implemented
on_connect() ...
on_diconnect() ...
mqtt_service() to subscribe topic, establish broker connection and do a loop.start and a while1

```
    client.loop_start()    
# client.loop_forever()                 19/12/19 Du coup si on veux lire les Inputs fo fair un loop
print("> client.connected_flag= ", client.connected_flag, ".")
print("> client.bad_connection_flag= ", client.bad_connection_flag, ".")

while not client.connected_flag and not client.bad_connection_flag:                             #wait coonnection to broker .. usefull ??
    Print_savelog("[mqtt_service]: In wait loop to connect")
    time.sleep(1)
    Print_savelog('[mqtt_service]: client.connected_flag = ', client.connected_flag)
    Print_savelog('[mqtt_service]: client.bad_connection_flag = ', client.bad_connection_flag)

if client.bad_connection_flag:                                                                  # 20/12/19 PEUT etre là que ca ne reconnecte pas suite à coupure de jus et pas encore internet
    Print_savelog("[mqtt_service]: aaa")
    client.loop_stop()    #Stop loop
    sys.exit()

while 1:
    if (rx_en_crs==0):
        print("In the MQTT LOOP")
        toto.chk_position()
    #Print_savelog('> position [chk_position]2 = ', var.position_en_crs)

    #print(">2 var.position_ancienne = ", var.position_ancienne, ".")
    #print(">2 var.position_en_crs   = ", var.position_en_crs, ".")

        if ( (client.connected_flag == False) and (client.bad_connection_flag == True) ):
            Print_savelog('[mqtt_service]: into connected_flag=false & bad_connection_flag=true')
        if (var.position_ancienne!=var.position_en_crs ):
            Print_savelog('[mqtt_service]: > PUBLISHING position = ', var.position_en_crs)
            client.publish("mo/portail/position_portail",var.position_en_crs,1, True)
            var.position_ancienne=var.position_en_crs 

        time.sleep(1)      
    else:
        rx_en_crs=rx_en_crs
```

Sometimes there's some disconnection [on_disconnect] for reason 1 ?? (i don't know why...)
The client succeed to do a reconnection [on_connect] with result 0.
But after that it's impossible to receive any incoming Topic.

do i need to restart manually the loop ?? because the reconnection is automatic but not the loop??

Any idea?

Comment: You need to re-subscribe in your on_connect proc.